# How to suppress callback for jQuery Ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

When a user searches for something on my site, I want to log the search term. In the click event handler for the search button (on the client side), I am calling a function which logs the search term by making an AJAX request. I then load the search results page. The request to load the search results page is not made until the AJAX request to log the search term finishes. How can I speed it up? Can I suppress the callback for AJAX complete event?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're loading a new search results page, why use AJAX at all? Just log the search term server-side at the head of your the results page.

Comment: Sean's idea is probably the more sensible way to go. If you continue to use AJAX, you're always going to have that delay while the request makes it's trip to the server and back.

Comment: Sean's suggestion is the better approach. Thanks Sean. How do I mark your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the log function asynchronous so that you don't wait for it to finish.  The downside of this is that you will not be notified of any logging errors.

Alternatively, you can just have the server side database functions do the logging as part of your search procedure.

Comment: The logging function is asynchronous but the page waits for the request to finish before loading the target page.

Comment: Then you will need to handle it on the server side